# Rounded corner speech box with arrow and dropshadow. Image based

Tags: html, css

I need to style box, please see attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot of box]

- Height and weight could differ. It could be 150 x 200 px but also 600
  x 150 px.
- Internet Explorer 8 is must. Due to this sadly no CSS3
  technique could be used. IE 7 will not be supported.
- Shadow is bottom and right. But if somebody know solution for four sided shadow
  I´ll be also interested in.
- Prefer not to use JavaScript based solution as I don´t have good experience with various libraries.
- Clean construction instead of wrapping content in various divs. See
  "code mockoup".
- Position of arrow could differ. It could be on top, left etc.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<div class="leftTop"></div>
<div class="rightTop"></div>
<div class="leftBottom"></div>
<div class="rightBottom"></div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="dropdownContent">   

</div>                                          
</div>
```

As good start point I found [zara.com solution](http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/de/en/zara-W2011/126502/498019/TWO-TONE+JOGGING+COAT) ( expand e.g. shipping ). They use [such image](http://static.zara.net/wcsstore/ZaraStorefrontAssetStore/images/bg_dropdown_1750.png)

[image]

Con is that background color of wrapper couldn't be changed in CSS as it is part of image. But it's not so important.

Comment: What's your question? What part are you having trouble with? What have ***you*** tried already?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rounded corners, shadows and other CSS3 features if you use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/). Some features are a bit cpu intensive to emulate, but it gives you a more or less CSS3 compliant IE starting from version 6.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but worth mentioning the following pure CSS3 solution.  Given the following Less CSS:

```
// Tooltip Variables

@wcui_tt_radius: 6px;
@wcui_tt_arrow_size: 6px;
@wcui_tt_background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
@wcui_tt_foreground: white;
@wcui_tt_padding: 6px 10px;
@wcui_tt_font: 13px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
@wcui_tt_z: 100;
@wcui_tt_max_width: 200px;


// Mixins

.opacity(@opacity) {
  opacity: @opacity / 100;
  filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacity})";
}

.transition(@transition) {
  -webkit-transition: @transition;
     -moz-transition: @transition;
      -ms-transition: @transition;
       -o-transition: @transition;
          transition: @transition;
}

.border-radius(@radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
     -moz-border-radius: @radius;
          border-radius: @radius;
}


#arrow {
    .top(@arrowWidth: 5px, @color: black) {
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -@arrowWidth;

        border-left: @arrowWidth solid transparent;
        border-right: @arrowWidth solid transparent;
        border-bottom: @arrowWidth solid @color;
    }
    .bottom(@arrowWidth: 5px, @color: black) {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -@arrowWidth;

        border-left: @arrowWidth solid transparent;
        border-right: @arrowWidth solid transparent;
        border-top: @arrowWidth solid @color;
    }
    .left(@arrowWidth: 5px, @color: black) {
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        margin-top: -@arrowWidth;

        border-top: @arrowWidth solid transparent;
        border-bottom: @arrowWidth solid transparent;
        border-right: @arrowWidth solid @color;
    }
    .right(@arrowWidth: 5px, @color: black) {
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: -@arrowWidth;

        border-top: @arrowWidth solid transparent;
        border-bottom: @arrowWidth solid transparent;
        border-left: @arrowWidth solid @color;
    }
}


// Tooltip Styles
.tooltip {
    font: @wcui_tt_font;
    .opacity(0);
    .transition(opacity 0.15 ease);
    z-index: @wcui_tt_z;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;

    .on { .opacity(100); }

    .content {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: @wcui_tt_background;
        color: @wcui_tt_foreground;
        padding: @wcui_tt_padding;
        .border-radius(@wcui_tt_radius);
        max-width: @wcui_tt_max_width;
    }

    .arrow {
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    &.top {
        padding-top: @wcui_tt_arrow_size;
        .arrow { #arrow > .top(@wcui_tt_arrow_size, @wcui_tt_background); }
    }
    &.bottom {
        padding-bottom: @wcui_tt_arrow_size;
        .arrow { #arrow > .bottom(@wcui_tt_arrow_size, @wcui_tt_background); }
    }
    &.left {
        padding-left: @wcui_tt_arrow_size;
        .arrow { #arrow > .left(@wcui_tt_arrow_size, @wcui_tt_background); }
    }
    &.right {
        padding-right: @wcui_tt_arrow_size;
        .arrow { #arrow > .right(@wcui_tt_arrow_size, @wcui_tt_background); }
    }
}
```

It seems long, but it really isn't.  The mixins get re-used throughout your Less CSS code.  The HTML markup is straightforward:

```
<div class="tooltip left">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>This is a sample large tooltip.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

All that remains is to position it and somehow add the "on" class using something like jQuery when you want it to appear.  The result looks like:

[Tooltip Sample http://f.cl.ly/items/2u2Z1H011p2R1h1D0B3N/tips.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/2u2Z1H011p2R1h1D0B3N/tips.png)